# Converting unicode strings and vice-versa

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm kind of new to using *Unicode* string and pointers and I've no idea how the conversion to unicode to ascii and versa-versa works. Following is what I'm trying to do,

```
const wchar_t *p = L"This is a string";
```

If I wanted to convert it to `char*`, how would the conversion work with converting `wchar_t*` to `char*` and vice-versa?

or by value using `wstring` to `string` class object and vice-versa

```
std::wstring wstr = L"This is a string";
```

If i'm correct, can you just copy the string to a new buffer without conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions are platform-dependent. On Windows use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) API functions. On Unix/linux platforms [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) library is quite popular.

Comment: Beware that `MultiByteToWideChar` has a bug when converting codepage 50225 (Korean - ISO-2022-KR) which converts characters incorrectly as noted on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/960293 - The suggested workaround is to use `IMultiLanguage::ConvertStringToUnicode` instead which converts the same characters properly - please update answer to make this more visible.

Answer (score 23):

In the future (VS 2010 already supports it), this will be possible in standard C++ (finally!):

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
const std::wstring wide_string = L"This is a string";
const std::string utf8_string = converter.to_bytes(wide_string);
```

Comment: I think there is a typo `std::wstring` in the last line should be `std:string`

Comment: That the last line should be `std::string`: confirmed from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes

Answer (score 5):

The conversion from ASCII to Unicode and vice versa are quite trivial. By design, the first 128 Unicode values are the same as ASCII (in fact, the first 256 are equal to ISO-8859-1).

So the following code works on systems where `char` is ASCII and `wchar_t` is Unicode:

```
const char* ASCII = "Hello, world";
std::wstring Unicode(ASCII, ASCII+strlen(ASCII));
```

You can't reverse it this simple: 汉 does exist in Unicode but not in ASCII, so how would you "convert" it?

Comment: There is also from_bytes which you can use like ---  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;  const std::wstring wstring = converter.from_bytes(string);

Answer (score 3):

C++ by itself doesn't offer this functionality. You'll need a separate library, like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Answer (score 3):

C Standard library functions: `mbstowcs` and `wcstombs`

Answer (score 0):

The widen() algorithm converts `char` to `wchar_t` :

```
char a;
a = 'a';
whcar_t wa = cin.widen(a);
```

Of course, you have to put it into a loop. And resolve the *;
The opposite is accomplished by `narrow()`