# vector<string> in wxComboBox

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I hope my question is not to localized... But I think some other will stumble about this or a similar problem.

I want to create a vector which contains all available ports at my system (this works in a console app). After that I want to copy the vectorelements in a wxString-Array to get them in a wxComboBox.

So, in my particular case I get two errors:

1. the variablename of the vector is not known in wxWidgets
2. by copying, the wxString will cast my string into a wchar_t (I know, wchar_t and wxString are similar...)

I will add some of my Code, so you will have a better sight about the problem:

**first problem**

```
std::vector<std::string> v_ports;
v_ports.push_back = "Com1";
v_ports.push_back = "Com4";
```

--> *error: 'v_ports' does not name a type*
(hint: that is a example, in the hole programm I will use a function to get the strings)

**second problem**

```
wxString sect_opt[v_ports.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < v_ports.size(); i++)
    sect_opt[i] = _T(v_ports[i]);
```

--> *error: 'Lv_ports' was not declared in this scope*

I'm using:
IDE: CodeLite 5.1; wxW 2.9.4; @Win8.1

Comment: try `v_ports.push_back("Com1");`

Comment: O my God... I must have get to less sleep... but it's doesn't fix the problem

Comment: nothing wrong with your first problem now, see: http://ideone.com/s5LRGx

Comment: @billz: yes, both headers are included

Comment: @Dequing: if you has try it out in a console-app you will get no error, I've first create my function as console-app, but when I try to use the function with wxW the error raise.

Comment: Why are you using `_T()` wrapped around a **variable** ?? It's a literal-only wrapper for prepending (or not) `L` to character and string **literals** only, when building Unicode (or not) programs. Lose that wrapper and try `v_ports[i].c_str()` in that statement instead.

Answer (score 3):

#### First problem

Instead of using:

```
v_ports.push_back = "Com1";
v_ports.push_back = "Com4";
```

you should use:

```
v_ports.push_back("Com1");
v_ports.push_back("Com4");
```

because `std::vector<T>::push_back` is a function.

#### Second problem

The `_T` macro [is supposed to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48.aspx) be used on *literals*:

> Use the _T macro to conditionally code literal strings to be portable to Unicode.

It cannot be used in expressions like `_T(v_ports[i])`.

To convert a string to unicode please see:

- [Converting unicode strings and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4786292/493122) (Philipp's answer)
- [How well is Unicode supported in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17103925/493122)

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I'd love to improve my answer if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: `std::string` can be converted to `wxString` (doing the Unicode conversion in the process implicitly) directly, i.e. just writing `wxString(v_ports[i])` is enough if the string is ASCII (or encoded in the current locale encoding). Otherwise `wxString::FromUTF8()` could be useful.

Comment: Hi, and thanks, but how I write to Deqing, the error is still there, even when i use push_back as function. (I had forgot to update it here, I had must to tired this morning when i used push_back like above...) But the second problem is fixed now, thx.

Comment: @Casisto Please don't update your question with the solution. Leave it as it is. The solution stays in the answers.