# error C2664: 'void vtkImageReader2::SetFileName(const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *"

Tags: visual-c++, vtk

```
BOOL CTestBMPDoc::OnOpenDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    if (! CDocument::OnOpenDocument(lpszPathName))
        return FALSE;

    m_pvtkBMPReader = vtkBMPReader::New();
    m_pvtkBMPReader->SetFileName(lpszPathName);

    return TRUE;
 }
```

The above code doesn't compile and produces the C2664 error. Why?

Comment: as the error says, you are passing the wrong argument type to the function `setFileName`. it expects a `char*` and you provide a `LPCTSTR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VC++ project is setup as a *UNICODE* so all the references to `TCHAR` are resolved into a wide character type `w_char`. However your **vtk**'s `SetFileName()` function doesn't support *UNICODE* thus the compilation error.

To fix this you should either change the properties of your project to use ASCII or MBCS (depending on your needs) or do the manual *UNICODE*->*MBCS* (or into *ASCII*) conversion.

Below is an example on how to convert *UNICODE* into *MBCS* using system codepage:

```
const size_t fnameLen = 1024;
char * fname[fnameLen];
int converted = WideCharToMultibyte(
                      CP_ACP
                    , WC_COMPOSITECHECK | WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS
                    , lpszPathName
                    , -1 // null-terminated string
                    , fname
                    , fnameLen
                    , NULL // or whatever you'd like it to be
                    , NULL);
 m_pvtkBMPReader->SetFileName(fname); // <-- this should work now as it is char*
```

Please note that I have just written down that code without compiling, so expect that you may need some tweaking before this builds and runs properly.

ATL and MFC provide a [bunch of convenient macroses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) to simplify the string conversions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786292/converting-unicode-strings-and-vice-versa (Google is your friend ;-))