# Converting std::string to a typedef of wchar_t*

Tags: c++, typedef, wchar-t

I am reading in a file directory from the user through the console, and I must store the value in a `pxcCHAR*` variable, which is the SDK's `typedef` for `wchar_t*`.

I found that I can do the conversion from `std::string` to `std::wstring` by doing the following.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string stringPath;
    std::getline(std::cin, stringPath);
    std::wstring wstrPath = std::wstring(stringPath.begin(), stringPath.end());
    const wchar_t* wcharPath = wstrPath.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I see these values through debugging.

```
stringPath= "C:/Users/"
wstrPath= L"C:/Users/"
wcharPath= 0x00b20038 L"C:/Users/"
```

Where is the value concatenated to the front of `wcharPath` coming from?

Furthermore,

Because `pxcCHAR*` is a `typedef` for `wchar_t*`, I thought it would be okay to simply do this:

```
pxcCHAR* mFilePath = wcharPath;
```

However, I get a message saying that "const wchar_t*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "pxcCHAR*".

I expected implicit conversion to work, but it doesn't. How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unicode strings and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786292/converting-unicode-strings-and-vice-versa)

Comment: No point in discussing "converting" between string types without specifying what encoding you're using on either side of the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::wstring(stringPath.begin(), stringPath.end())` is the wrong way to deal with string conversions, unless you can guarantee that you are only dealing with 7bit ASCII data (which is not the case with the filesystem). This type of conversion doesn't account for character encodings at all.  The correct way to convert a `std::string` to `std::wstring` is to use `std::wstring_convert`, `MultiByteToWideChar()`, or other equivalent.  There are plenty of examples of this if you look around.

Better would be to just use `std::wstring` to begin with instead of `std::string`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::wstring stringPath;
    std::getline(std::wcin, stringPath);
    const wchar_t* wcharPath = stringPath.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

> Where is the value concatenated to the front of `wcharPath` coming from?

The debugger. It is simply showing you the memory address that the pointer is pointing at, followed by the actual character data at that address.

> I get a message saying that "const wchar_t*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "pxcCHAR*".

That means `pxcCHAR` is not a typedef of `const wchar_t`, but is more likely a typedef of just `wchar_t` by itself. You cannot assign a `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer, regardless of the type used.  If you need to make this kind of assignment, you have to type-cast the `const` away, such as with `const_cast`:

```
pxcCHAR* mFilePath = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wcharPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Converting Unicode and ANSI Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You should use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).

That being said, is very unlikely you ever need to do this (and is very likely the result is incorrect for any code page *not* [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)). What you probably have to is use wide strings *everywhere*.

Oh, and read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).